# Environment variable doesn't work in Assets field settings

Tags: assets, field, environmentvariables

I created an environment variable (in *config/general.php*) called `{baseAssetPath}` which contains the server path to the folder where all my assets are stored. This makes it easier to populate the *Path* field in *Assets* settings.

However, this variable does not appear to work to configure the *Upload Location* when setting up an *Assets* field. Now, when I attempt to add an asset, or edit an existing entry, I get the following error.

```
Internal Server Error

Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not
have a method or closure named
"baseAssetPath".
```

Is *Upload Location* looking for a server path or a URL path?

If it's looking for a server path, why doesn't my `{baseAssetPath}` variable work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Upload Location" doesn't reference you're environment variables. Instead, you've got a dropdown menu of your pre-defined Assets sources. Whichever one you choose will be used as the base of your file path.

Anything you put in curly braces after that will become a *subfolder* of that asset source. So your subfolder names will be created based on whichever **Entry fields** you define.

[image: Upload Location]

Comment: Ah, I see. I was confused by the placeholder text in that field, which is the same as the placeholder text in the server path field in _Assets_ settings. That makes more sense now.